# Too many '/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start' processes

Tags: php, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm facing a problem with apache processes (/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start) visible in HTOP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmJtu.png)
After every refresh or connection from a client the number of processes increase without stopping to run.
Even if the browser is closed, the proces continues.
In every php page with a connection to the database I end with:

```
    $thread_id = $mysqli->thread_id;
    $mysqli->kill($thread_id);
    $mysqli->close();
```

After a while my raspberry PI 3 is running very slow and actually too hot.
I have a default installation of apache with the default settings.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian)
Server built:   2019-10-15T19:53:42
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:84
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

In the mpm_prefork.conf file I have:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers        4
    MinSpareServers     1
    MaxSpareServers     4
    MaxRequestWorkers   50
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

What can I do or set to automatically kill these processes after a client leaves the pages or closes the browser?
Or are there any settings in apache to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it only for HTTP connections where PHP connects to the database?

Answer (score 1):

The default Apache multi-process mode is a cpu-intensive Fork-based model. That means as the number of requests grows, so will the number of processes Apache starts (`http2`). Forking is CPU-intensive and can easily overwhelm the Pi. To use a more efficient multi-process model, try [`mpm_worker_module`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html), as it uses threading to handle increased throughput and the number of parent processes can be limited via configuration.

For more information on the MPM options for Apache2, [see the "Choosing an MPM" section of this document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html#compiletime).

The default, `prefork` module:

> The prefork MPM uses multiple child processes with one thread each. Each process handles one connection at a time. On many systems, prefork is comparable in speed to worker, but it uses more memory. Prefork's threadless design has advantages over worker in some situations: it can be used with non-thread-safe third-party modules, and it is easier to debug on platforms with poor thread debugging support.

Proposed `worker` module:

> The worker MPM uses multiple child processes with many threads each. Each thread handles one connection at a time. Worker generally is a good choice for high-traffic servers because it has a smaller memory footprint than the prefork MPM.

Here is an example configuration that may work:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          2 # how many processes max?
    StartServers         1 # how many processes start initially?
    MaxRequestWorkers   40 # maximum total number of threads that may be launched
    MinSpareThreads     25
    MaxSpareThreads     75
    ThreadsPerChild     20 # number of threads deployed by each child process
</IfModule>
```

Note that your Apache2 installation must be compiled *with* the MPM you intend to use. [The docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html#compiletime) have more information on this.